# Windows 2008R2 RAS does not works after install KB4524157

Tags: vpn, windows-update, windows-server-2008-r2, shared-folders, pptp

I'm using a WINDOWS 2008R2 STD as a VPN (PPTP remote access server) server. 
The clients are connect to the shared folder in internal network via WIN 2008 server with PPTP.

Today morning, I found that every clients are can not access to the shared folder on the internal network.
The clients were assigned internal IP correctly.
And, the shared folders were could access at Windows 2008 server.
Ping from internal server to the client was available.
But, could not access to the shared folder on the internal network.

I found KB4524157 had installed during the weekend. 
After remove the KB4524157, The access became normal. 
So, I removed KB4524157 temporally now.

May I have advice about this?
The clients are using Windows7, Windows10.

Regards.
Andrei.

Comment: Sounds like the patch introduces an incompatibility with your setup.  However, the update is only applicable to Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7.  So why did you make mention of the Windows 10 clients?

Comment: Because, every clients could not access to the shared folder. Whatever It's OS. I just tried to brief my environments as detail as I can.